# Careful About Zugos Today?

Tags: halacha

Should we be careful for zugos (eating or drinking an even number of foods) today?

Although I initially thought we were not careful for zugos based on the fact the [Beis Yosef OC (170:7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.170.1?lang=bi&p2=Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.170.7&lang2=bi) questions the [Tur (170)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.170.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for bringing zugos and the Shulchan Aruch doesn't mention anything, the [Aruch Hashulchan YD (116:17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.17?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> ובזמנינו לא שמענו מקפידים בזוגות רק אם יש מקפידים יתנהגו כמ"ש
>
> Nowadays we haven't heard people are strict for
> zugos, but if there are [people] who are careful...

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27203/13811 , https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84467/13811

Comment: Wouldn’t be the first time the Aruch HaShulchan says we’re careful about something which is potentially a danger which the Mechaber doesn’t bring down. Cf. leaving the peel on eggs and onions.

Comment: A big part of the concept is ,the more you are involved in it the more there is a concern.

Comment: @sam True to a large extent, though I heard a few Rabbonim mention that people often don't quote the last part of that line of the Gemara Pesachim (110b) where it seems to point to being concerned - במערבא לא קפדי אזוגי רב דימי מנהרדעא קפיד אפילו ארושמא דחביתא הוה עובדא ופקע חביתא כללא דמילתא כל דקפיד קפדי בהדיה ודלא קפיד לא קפדי בהדיה ומיהו למיחש מיבעי

Comment: I believe Rabbi Yehuda Hachaasid in his last piece also writes about the more people get involved the more they have to worry.

Answer (score 3):

From what it seems is that the more one is concerned about zugos the more they have to worry about it. The Ben Ish Chai [(Ben Yoyada Pesachim 109b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Pesachim.109b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that in his times the minhag in Bagdad was to specifically send zugos. He writes that when there was a simcha the women would send baskets of sweets and specifically sent in pairs in order to be mevatel(negate) the concern for zugos which was prevalent in the beginning(times of the Gemara).

Text of Ben Yoyada:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mention the fact that he says the power of sheidim with respect to zugos is gone in our times